# Fastlane: Could not find action, lane or variable '​'

Tags: fastlane

When running `bundle exec fastlane build`, fastlane prints the following error message (The character between the quotes is U+200B zero width space):

```
[!] Could not find action, lane or variable '​'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
```

Fastlane: 2.130.0
Gem: 3.0.6

Did anyone ever experience this problem? If yes, how did you fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the problem: I had a zero-width space character somewhere in my Fastfile.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Gem File doesn't contained fastlane folder path got to project folder and find Gemfile click Edit and update the same.

**Before Update**

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "fastlane"

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), '**.**', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)

**After Update**

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "fastlane"

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), '**fastlane**', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)

Answer (score 0):

In My case it showed `could not find action, lane or variable 'appcenter_upload'`
So I had to install the AppCenter plugin :
using
`fastlane add_plugin appcenter`

Answer (score 0):

Add `|options|` in front of your lane.